# Selector as Property Question

Tags: cocoa, notifications

in my class I have this property: `@property SEL didStartRestoreSelector;` and then synthesize it as such `@synthesize didStartRestoreSelector;`.

In my class, I have the following line: `[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:didStartRestoreSelector name:@"restoreHasStarted" object:nil];`

I want myself to be able to set the selector myself using the property, but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. This is how I did it:

```
USBBackupFramework*framework = [[USBBackupFramework alloc] init];
framework.didBeginBackupSelector = @selector(didBegin);
```

Unfortunately `didBegin` never gets called. Instead, the console outputs this:

```
2010-12-05 20:27:24.376 Framework Test App[5228:a0f] -[USBBackupFramework <null selector>]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10013f0d0
```

The selector is not null though, I did set one.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `addObserver:` line in the `init` method of your class? If so, then it will be using the value of `didStartRestoreSelector` or `didBeginBackupSelector` as it happened to exist at that point in time (which will be `NULL`). Any changes you make after the initialization won't be automatically picked up.

Instead, you could modify the constructor to take selectors at the time of initialization, or you could implement the property dynamically, so that `setDidStartRestoreSelector:` will de- and re-register the object for distributed notifications.

Comment: you could also be key-value observing your own `didStart*Selector`, and then in the observation method, unregister the old observation selector and register the new one